# Restrict Gutenberg Blocks to Single Use

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

I've got my blocks registered properly and functioning.
My only gripe is that I don't want the blocks to be used more than once in the same post.
Is it possible to restrict block behavior like this? The documentation is horrible.

Comment: You can try exploring the block editor's data by using `wp.data.select("core/editor").getBlocks()` from `core/block-editor` and use `wp.data.dispatch("core/editor").lockPostSaving("lock_key")` to prevent the post from saving...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who needs this too, here is how you restrict a block for single use only:

```
// A Sample Block
acf_register_block(array(
    'name'              => 'blockname',
    'title'             => __('Block Name','slug'),
    'description'       => __('A translatable description','slug'),
    'render_callback'   => 'theme_block_render',
    'category'          => 'embed', //the block category (optional)
    'align'             =>  'wide', // default value for width
    'mode'              => 'auto', // default value for switching auomatically between edit and view mode
    'supports'          => array('align' => array('wide','full' ),'multiple' => false), // wide and full are optional, those are for setting the width. SET MULTIPLE TO FALSE HERE!
    'icon'              => 'welcome-view-site', // Use a dashicon, for example dashicons-welcome-view-site
    'keywords'          => array( 'blockname', 'image','text' ), //set some keywords for search
));
```

Further documentation can be found here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_register_block_type/

Comment: Starting at ACF 6.0 you can use the `supports: {multiple: false}` in `block.json` like a normal block

Answer (score 11):

When registering your own blocks, you can set the `multiple` option of the `supports` property to `false`:

```
supports: {
    // Use the block just once per post
    multiple: false
}
```

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-supports/#multiple.

Answer (score 1):

in block.json set "multiple" to **false** in "supports":

```
"category": "widgets",
"icon": "smiley",
"supports": {
    "html": false,
    "multiple": false
},
"attributes": {
```